# TextView in a viewpager

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` with a `ViewPager` containing multiple `fragments`. How can I now access a `TextView` in one of that `fragments` to change its text from the main `activity`? I tried multiple ways and they all ended with errors
this is My `headerAdapter`

```
 public class HeaderAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
     private List<Fragment> fragments;
     public HeaderAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragments) {
         super(fm);
         this.fragments=fragments;
     }

     @Override
     public Fragment getItem(int position) {
         return this.fragments.get(position);
     }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
         return this.fragments.size();
     }
```

And my header.xml contains an imageview and a text view like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/fj"
         android:textColor="#ff0000"
         android:textSize="100dp"
         android:text="aaa"
         />
     <ImageView
         android:alpha="0.7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="203dp"
         android:id="@+id/head1"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:src="@drawable/dash_widget_0"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

My view pager like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:weightSum="1">

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="203dp"
         android:id="@+id/header_pager"
        >
     </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

in `mainActivity` I need to change the `textView`?

Comment: Do you have the fragment code ? Easiest way would be to update the text view from your fragment not from the main activity

Comment: "I tried multiple ways and they all ended with errors" - It would be useful if you showed what you tried so people don't suggest the same things. Generally, though, you could try `fragments.get(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.textView)`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access the textview from activity. That would be very hard to understand later and also that would cause total mess in your code.

What you should do is to implement public methods that do the work inside of a fragment. Accessing this method can be done in a super easy way by calling `(YOUR_FRAGMENT_TYPE)HeaderAdapter#getItem(index)`. To avoid exceptions in casting the types check the Fragment with `instanceOf`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though their might be a better way to implement what you are doing. You can get a reference to your Fragment from a view pager using this method

```
private Fragment getFragmentFromPager(int index) {
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.header_pager + ":" + index);
}
```

Just keep a public reference to your TextView inside the Fragment so you can access it.